# Multidimensional arrays from a GET/POST request in Django

Tags: php, arrays, django, multidimensional-array

php array:

```
$post = [
  'contact' => [ // <--
      ['phone' => '1234', 'lname'=>'Anton'], 
      ['phone' => '123', 'lname'=>'Sima']
  ] // <--
];
```

or GET URL:

```
contact[][phone]=1234&contact[][lname]=Anton
```

How can I get data in this format using Django request ?
I used https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser, its result does not suit me, it deletes duplicate keys

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can i get this array in django with request.POST['phone']

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't use duplicate keys, you need to add another array around them, if you want something like your example:

```
$post = [
    'contact' => [ // <--
        ['phone' => '1234', 'lname'=>'Anton'], 
        ['phone' => '123', 'lname'=>'Sima']
    ] // <--
];
```